# How to use two foreign keys as a composite key in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm working spring-mvc web application using Hibernate. In this, I have Database Structure like this.

```
Table A
    --------
    A1 (Pk)
    A2
    ...

    Table B
    --------
    B1 (Pk)
    B2
    ...

    Table C
    --------
    A1 (Fk)
    B1 (Fk)
    C1
    C2
```

Table C doesn't have primary key. Is it possible use two foreign keys as composite key?
If possible, Please tell me how to map two foreign keys as composite key in Hibernate using annotations.

Comment: You may want to read this.  A many-to-many with properties.  http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2010/12/26/many-to-many-relationships-with-properties.aspx

Comment: You can try here too.  Note, I live in the NHibernate world, but it should cross-over.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923079/fluent-nhibernate-many-to-many-relationship-with-attribute-on-relationship